# Index binary file as part of a document

Tags: solr

Is it possible to provide an XML file for Solr to index and have PDF, Word, ... file(s) alongside that need to be indexed together with the XML?

I know that Tica can index PDF/Word but my binary files are actually "attachments" to a file I'm indexing.

Comment: why do you want to index binary file?i guess it's better to store it somewhere else

Comment: I want to index the content of the binary files.